# How do you send an email from a Yahoo server via JavaMail?

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail, yahoo

I've been trying to find a site which is updated to the newest version of JavaMail, but whenever I try I get this annoying error (Debug enabled)
Help?

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.5
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.rsetbeforequit: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.disabletop: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.forgettopheaders: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.cachewriteto: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.filecache.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.keepmessagecontent: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.starttls.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.starttls.required: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.apop.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.disablecapa: false
DEBUG POP3: connecting to host "pop.mail.yahoo.com", port 110, isSSL false
S: +OK hello from popgate-0.8.0.357900 pop001.mail.ir2.yahoo.com 
C: CAPA
S: +OK CAPA list follows
IMPLEMENTATION popgate-0.8.0.357900
XOIP
EXPIRE-NEVER
PIPELINING
RESP-CODES
TOP
UIDL
USER
SASL LOGIN PLAIN
STLS
.
DEBUG POP3: PIPELINING enabled
DEBUG POP3: authentication command trace suppressed
DEBUG POP3: authentication command failed
C: QUIT
S: +OK
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [AUTH] Access to this service is not permitted.
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:208)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at dong.pong.ping.Client.main(Client.java:42)
```

**Code:**

```
String smtpHost = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
        String popHost = "pop.mail.yahoo.com";
        String from = "classified@yahoo.com";
        String to = "classified@yahoo.com";
        String username = "classified";
        String password = "secret";

        // Get system properties
        Properties props = System.getProperties();

        // Setup mail server
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", 587);

        // Get session
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        session.setDebug(true);

        Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
        store.connect(popHost, username, password);

        // Define message
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, 
          new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject("Hello JavaMail");
        message.setText("Welcome to Yahoo's JavaMail");

        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);
```

If any of you have a working code, could you post it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have premium account?

> Or is it a Yahoo problem?
>
> Moved to the appropriate forum, but some versions of yahoo (specifically yahoo.com) do not support POP3 access to mail unless you have signed up for a premium account or have a partner service (like AT&T/Yahoo). When it says "Access is not permitted", that's probably what it means - you don't have a premium account.

[[AUTH] Access to this service is not permitted](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/findpost.pl?id=11622772)

**EDIT: see also [Java Mail: Unable to send email via Yahoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533394/java-mail-unable-to-send-email-via-yahoo?rq=1) for working example.**

Answer (score 0):

According to various websites I've seen, the SMTP port for Yahoo is 465

- http://email.about.com/od/accessingyahoomail/f/Yahoo_Mail_SMTP_Settings.htm

---

Actually, now that I look at the stack trace, it looks like the problem is occurring when you attempt to connect to the POP3 store.  If you are just trying to *send* email, I don't know why you would need to connect to POP3 at all.

Comment: Thanks, but still can't send.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked [this page](http://email.about.com/od/accessingyahoomail/f/Yahoo_Mail_SMTP_Settings.htm) and it seems that your username must be the full address, so you have to change:

```
String username = "classified";
```

To:

```
String username = "classified@yahoo.com";
```

And the SMTP of yahoo is 465 using TLS/SSL.

```
 props.put("mail.smtp.port", 465);
```

Comment: Would it be because my username and password is wrong?
Still the same error.

Comment: Can't say without the stacktrace

Comment: And why your stacktrace shows a POP3 exception if you are in smtp? Oh sorry, read wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this one using Spring Framework Mail service. It works for me:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost("smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
        mailSender.setPort(587);
        mailSender.setUsername("username1");
        mailSender.setPassword("password");
        mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(props);

        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();

        message.setFrom(email);
        message.setTo(email);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(text);
        mailSender.send(message);
```